# How to prevent annotation outside of Document?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pspdfkit

I am using an older version of PSPDFKit, 3.7.0, and I want to limit the ink and other annotations to the PSPDFDocument/Page and not draw on the whole PSPDFViewController. I tried clipToPageBoundaries but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

We've solved this a few years ago - PSPDFKit at the time I'm writing this is not at v6.4. While I can't recall the details, we introduced clipping logic in [PSPDFDrawView](https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFDrawView.html) but there've been so many changes that it's impossible to explain in detail. We've also changed drawing from being image-based to using shapes/OpenGL a while back to greatly improve performance, especially for larger drawings.

PSPDFKit is a commercial SDK for iOS, Android and Web. We can only keep working on it because of our amazing customers that support us every year with renewing their subscription. Feel free to [contact our sales team](https://pspdfkit.com/#contactsales) if you want to save yourself from the trouble of manually trying to fix bugs in a many-year-old codebase with [a long list of known bugs](https://pspdfkit.com/changelog/ios/) that we fixed since then.

Support and Updates are always tied together as a package, but maybe this answer helps you out a bit.

--
 Peter, Founder of PSPDFKit

Comment: Thanks for the info! Just to be sure I understood correctly, in 3.7.0 is not possible to limit the drawing to the PSPDFPageView bounds?

Comment: I did not say that - It might be possible (and you can try with the tips I gave above) but this version is just way too old to offer any kind of support for it. I highly recommend updating to a newer release.

Comment: Ok, got it now.Thanks again and will upgrade asap.